# Указатели внутри функций в C

Tags: c, указатели

В функцию передаётся указатель на корень B-дерева и число, которое нужно вставить в дерево:

```
void bt_insert(Tree** tree_ptr, const int key);
```

далее, ищется узел, в который можно вставить данные:

```
if (!(*tree_ptr)->is_leaf) node = bt_get_node(*tree_ptr, key);
else node = *tree_ptr;
```

после вставки данных в дерево, оно, при необходимости балансируется

```
if (node->count != DEGREE) return;
bt_balance(&node);
```

Но в случае, если нужно отбалансировать корневой элемент, `tree_ptr` и `node` имеют разные значения. То есть, если

```
else node = *tree_ptr;
```

То `tree_ptr != &node`

И я не могу вставить вместо `*tree_ptr` другой узел в функции `bt_balance` (согласно алгоритма).

Что тут можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то объявите `node` как

```
Tree **node;
```

и используйте

```
node = tree_ptr;
```

или еще один фрагмент

```
if ( ( *node )->count != DEGREE) return;
bt_balance( node );
```

Возможно, в некоторых местах вам надо будет объявить еще одну промежуточную переменную, как

```
Tree *tmp;
```

и использовать конструкцию

```
node = &tmp;
```

для передачи `node` в другие функции, которые требуют объект типа `Tree **`

Или

```
Tree *tmp;
//...
if (!(*tree_ptr)->is_leaf) tmp = bt_get_node(*tree_ptr, key);
//...
node = &tmp;
```

или в зависимости от условий

```
node = tree_ptr;
```

Comment: А как быть с `node = bt_get_node(*tree_ptr, key);`?

Comment: @zooZooz Смотрите мой дополненный ответ.

Comment: есть ещё такой забавный момент: `Node* root = *tree_ptr;`, а вот после этого `&root == tree_ptr` возвращает `0`

Comment: @zooZooz Как я уже написал правильно будет Node **roort; root = tree_ptr; Если вы хотите изменить исходные указатели, то вам надо объявлять ссылку на них и передавать в другие функции по ссылке. То есть надо будет использовать двойной указатель.

Comment: а можете, пожалуйста, объяснить мой 2 комментарий? Я уже просто не знаю, что мне делать, мой пробел в теории с указателями на указатели не позволяет двигаться дальше

Comment: @zooZooz &root - 'это адрес переменной root, Хотя сама переменная содержит значение *tree_ptr, тем не менее ее адрес отличается от того, что хранится в tree_ptr.. То есть в левой части выражения &root == tree_ptr вычисляется адрес переменной root, а в правой части выражения вычисляется значение, хранимое в переменной tree_ptr. Они не равны между собой.